# Sequelize - N:M Association Count Number of Included Model with Condition

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have two models: `Articles` and `Tags`. These models are associated to each other by `belongsToMany`, so an article may have many tags, and tags can be used by many articles.

**models**

```js
Articles.belongsToMany(Tags, {
    foreignKey: 'articleId', 
    as: 'tags', 
});

Tags.belongsToMany(Articles, {
    foreignKey: 'tagId', 
    as: 'articles', 
});
```

When querying, I need to get articles that has `searchTag` as tag, but get all tag information associated to article.

What I tried is:

```js
const articles = await Articles.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: Tags, 
        as: 'tags', 
        where: {
            tag: searchTag, 
        }, 
        attributes: ['id', 'tag'], 
        required: true, 
    }], 
    where: { 
        // querying condition
    }, 
});
```

but this code gets the matching tag only, which fails to get **all tags** that belongs to the article.

Another solution I thought was to check if any tag that `tag=searchTag` exists in `tags`, but I have no idea how to fit this condition into `sequelize` object. What is the proper way to fit this condition into `sequelize` object? Or any other way to solve this problem other than getting all `id`s of articles that has `searchedTag` and get all articles based on the `id`s?

Answer (score 0):

You have to query for your searchTag in the top where clause.

```js
const articles = await Articles.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: Tags, 
        as: 'tags', 
        // where: {
        //    tag: searchTag, 
        // }, 
        attributes: ['id', 'tag'], 
        required: true, 
    }], 
    where: { 
       $tags.id$': searchTag // <-- New
    }, 
});
```

By querying inside the include part, you get only the filtered tags like you described in your post.

Comment: I tried this before, but I got `Unknown column 'tags.id' in 'where clause'` error. I think it's because it's many-to-many relation, not one-to-many.

Comment: I also tried this, but still the tags are filtered.